# XML parsing issues in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, parsing, xmp

I got a problem in parsing the following xml:

```
<x:xmpmeta x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.0.0-ac001" xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
 <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmp:rating="4" xmp:title="random" xmp:land="stuff" 
    xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"/>
 </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

I would like to have a list of xmp's description and a list of its values:

```
-rating -title -land
```

and

```
-4 -random -stuff
```

I tried different parsings but no success because of the colons.

Thanks a lot for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the [XMP Library](http://adobe.com/devnet/xmp/).

```
var m:XMPMeta = new XMPMeta(xml);   

for each (var prop:XMPProperty in m)  
{  
    trace(prop.qname.localName);  
}  

for each (var value:XMPProperty in m)  
{
        trace(value);  
}   

// traces
rating   
title  
land  
4  
random  
stuff
```

If you want to access individual properties you can you use [XMPConst](http://cssdk.host.adobe.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/references/XMPASLib/XMPConst.htm) which provides most of the namespaces needed.

```
var xmp:Namespace = XMPConst.xmp;
trace(m.xmp::rating); //etc
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create Namespace objects for all the namespaces you want to access, and prefix your E4X properties with the appropriate namespaces. Here is an example of how you could read values and iterate over attributes:

```
var xmlString:String =
  '<x:xmpmeta x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.0.0-ac001" xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">\
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">\
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmp:rating="4" xmp:title="random" xmp:land="stuff" \
      xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"/>\
   </rdf:RDF>\
  </x:xmpmeta>';
var rdf:Namespace = new Namespace('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#');
var xmp:Namespace = new Namespace('http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/');
var xml:XML = new XML(xmlString);
for each (var description:XML in xml.rdf::RDF.rdf::Description) {
  var rating:String = description.@xmp::rating;
  var title:String = description.@xmp::title;
  var land:String = description.@xmp::land;
  trace(rating, title, land);

  // iterate over all the attributes
  for each (var attr:XML in description.attributes()) {
    trace(attr.name(), attr.localName());
  }
}
```